# Move or equalize last elements using Laravel collection chunk method

Tags: laravel, collections, chunks

I'm working with Laravel (9.x) collections and using chunk to split into 3 records. The last column only has one record and I need to move the last record of the previous column to the last column so that both have two.

Current result:

[image: Current result using chunk]

Expected result (Last two columns with two records each)

[image: Expected result using chunk]

How can I achieve this using Laravel Chunk or simply PHP's array functions? This is my current code:

```
     <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Hour</th>
                <th>Player</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($players->chunk(3) as $player)
                @foreach ($player->sortBy('index') as $detail)
                    <tr>
                        <td class="font-weight-bold">{{ $loop->parent->iteration }}</td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $detail->hour }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-left">
                            {{ $detail->name }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I don't know why you need this, you can achieve this with a simple algorithm using collection's methods:

```php
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Hour</th>
            <th>Player</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @php
            $chunkedPlayers = $players->chunk(3);
            $lastChunk = $chunkedPlayers->pop();
            
            if ($lastChunk->count() === 1) {
                $secondLastChunk = $chunkedPlayers->pop();
                $lastChunk->prepend($secondLastChunk->pop());
                $chunkedPlayers->push($secondLastChunk);
            }

            $chunkedPlayers->push($lastChunk);
        @endphp
        @foreach ($chunkedPlayers as $player)
            @foreach ($player->sortBy('index') as $detail)
                <tr>
                    <td class="font-weight-bold">{{ $loop->parent->iteration }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $detail->hour }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-left">
                        {{ $detail->name }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#available-methods

Comment: It's precisely what I needed. Now my question is, how can I do this when the collection is with chunk(4) so that there are 3 records in the last two columns? Thank you.